# Variable assignment if it doesn't exist

Tags: ruby

I want to assign an object to a variable containing another variable unless that variable doesn't exist, in which case I want to assign an empty object.

I have this code which works:

```
if @myvar['one']['two']
  newvar = {:three => @config['one']['two']}
else
  input = {}
end
```

Is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: What is `@myvar`? What is `@myvar['one']`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like:

```
newvar = if @myvar['one']['two']
           {:three => @config['one']['two']}
         else
           {}
         end
```

You could then use `newvar` as the variable assigned either to a populated hash or an empty hash.  Additionally, you'll want to check to ensure `@myvar` exists, and  has a key of `'one'` before calling `'two'`:

```
newvar = if @myvar && @myvar.has_key?('one') && @myvar['one']['two']
           {:three => @config['one']['two']}
         else
           {}
         end
```

Comment: `@myvar.has_key?('one')` raise an error if `@myvar` is `nil`

Comment: also, the original code is expecting two different variables depending on conditions: newvar and input

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code works... In one line:

```
@myvar['one']['two'] ? newvar = {:three => @config['one']['two']} : input = {}
```

If you want to prevent a nil `@myvar` and ensure it has a key of `one` and `two`:

```
@myvar && @myvar.has_key?('one') && @myvar['one']['two'] ? newvar = {:three => @config['one']['two']} : input = {}
```

Comment: The only issue with this ternary is if `@myvar['one']` doesn't exist, `['two']` will result in a NilClass error.

Comment: Fair, but I don't like assuming anything. ;-)